# Checking for messages existence

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I use a method like this for sending error messages to my facelet:

```
public static void addErrorMessage(String msg) {
        FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
    }
```

Then I show them inside a dialog with:

```
<p:messages id="messagesFattura" autoUpdate="true" />
```

And that works well. Now, my question is:

**how can I "check" for messages existence?**

I mean, there's another portion of code (a primefaces ) which I want to show/hide conditionally, via the *rendered* attribute.

I already tried the `#{empty facesContext.messageList}` EL variable, without success (*empty list*)

Comment: do you want to show a component if there is any FacesMessage and hide otherwise?

Comment: cann't you store the message status in a boolean?

Comment: uhm... no I won't do that... Aren't jsf messages supposed to work that way?

Comment: @FabioB.,describe what you mean by "no success".  `not empty facesContext.messageList` is what will check for the existence of messages. Beyond that, it's most likely it's your conditional rendering semantics are wrong. Post some code

Comment: I just added a message via my method addErrorMessage() posted above, it renders correctly in the view inside "messagesFattura". However, if I print #{facesContext.messageList} I see... []